# How to flatten Linq-To-Sql table mappings?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, mapping, denormalization

I have a Linq-To-Sql mapping between POCO classes and my DB. I want to be able to add properties on my classes which represent slightly more complex constructs than simple scalr values.

For instance, I have a custom struct type which holds two simple scalar values. I don't want to make this another table and then add a FK as the property. Is it possible to map this struct's properties using the Linq-to-Sql XML mapping file?

For instance,

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Blah { get; set; }
    public Bar Yada { get; set; }
}

public struct Bar
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```

How would I specify that `Blah`, `Yada.A`, and `Yada.B` are all persisted as columns on the `Foo` table?

**Can this even be done?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really lame, but sounds like it might need to be what I have to do if I stick with L2S.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Blah { get; set; }

    public int Bar_A { get; set; }
    public int Bar_B { get; set; }

    /* not mapped to DB */
    public Bar Yada
    {
        get { return new Bar { A = this.Bar_A, B = this.Bar_B }; }
        set { this.Bar_A = value.A; this.Bar_B = value.B; }
    }
}

public struct Bar
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, in the real code, I'd probably make it such that it wasn't creating the value over and over because my real `Bar` type has more to it than simply containing the values.

Answer (score 1):

I think Entity Framework in .NET4 is required to get this done. See [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200924084743/http://geekswithblogs.net/iupdateable/archive/2009/11/24/getting-started-with-entity-framework-4-ndash-complex-types-and.aspx) on complex types and entities.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm really hoping to stick with LINQ-to-SQL for this small app. If I jumped to EF, I'd really have to step back and look at NHibernate and others too.